# dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure)

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

Hi i have encountered with an error in dpkg. Below are the details:

```
$ sudo dpkg --audit | more
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 ubuntu-emulator      Create and run emulator images of Ubuntu Touch
 ubuntu-emulator-runtime:i386 Ubuntu Touch emulator runtime

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 less                 pager program similar to more
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
```

It would be great if i get the solution for this error.

Comment: Could you add full output of `sudo apt-get -f install` to the question?

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue by running the following:

```bsh
dpkg --force-depends --purge libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get -f install
```

At this point only unity was still "broken".

Afterwards, to fix that, run:

```bsh
dpkg --force-depends --purge unity
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: i have the following commands :

Comment: dpkg --force-depends --purge libgl1-mesa-glx and sudo apt-get -f install .  It results : Errors were encountered while processing:
 less
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 ubuntu-emulator-runtime:i386
 ubuntu-emulator
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)